# Не могу зайти в свою директорию | rbash

Tags: linux

После установки пользователю `rbash` он не может зайти в свою папку

```
someuser@Debian:~$ mkdir test
someuser@Debian:~$ cd test
-rbash: cd: restricted
```

Как править? И подскажите как убрать

```
someuser@Debian:~$ cat /etc/passwd
(полный вывод этого файла)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш bash запущен с опцией `-r` или прям как rbash. Открываем документацию и там написано, что в этом случае есть много ограничений. В том числе и запрет на переход по каталогам. Так что запускайте нормальный bash/zsh и все будет хорошо.

А запретить вывод файла... или это rbash был не случайно запущен?